# Referring to id part of URL in extJS

Tags: javascript, url, extjs

I'm new to Javascript and extJS, so please bear with me.

I have a webpage displaying a form using extJS.

The url identifies the object which should get displayed in the form. It looks like:

http://some.url.com/myapp/user/23

What is the idiomatic way to access the 23 part from the url, in order to load the correct data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the ID, do the following:

```
var id = document.location.href.split("/").reverse()[0];
```